# Discord.py on_message event function not running

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio, minecraft

I am trying to write a discord bot that will allow me to run and control a Minecraft server.

I am running the server as a subprocess:

```
def start(self):

        if self.process:
            self.process.kill()
            self.process = None

        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            ["java", "-jar", self.jar_file, "nogui"],
            cwd=self.directory,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
```

and am using this function to handle the console output:

```
 async def start_console(self, channel):
        while True:
            output = self.process.stdout.readline()
            if not output:
                break
            output = output.decode().strip()
            await channel.send(output)
```

which I am running as an asyncio task.

However, when I start the server and create the task (which works), the on_message function doesn't appear to be run whenever a message is sent.

I am using the on_message function to handle any commands that a user would send to the server and also to stop the server, for example, typing 'stop' in the channel that the console is sent would stop the server.

Update:

I am creating the task in the callback for a button

```
    async def start_button_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        
        if server.process:
            server.stop()
                
        server.start()

        channel = bot.get_channel(server.channel_id)

        server.console = asyncio.create_task(server.start_console(channel))
```

The code for my on_message looks like this;

```
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.channel.category == message.guild.categories[-1]:
        server_name = message.channel.name

        for server in active_servers:
            if server.name.lower() == server_name:
                command = message.content

                await message.delete()

                if command.upper() == 'STOP':
                    command += '\n'
                    server.process.stdin.write(command.encode())
                    server.process.stdin.flush()
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
                    server.console_task.cancel()
                    server.stop()
                else:
                    command += '\n'
                    server.process.stdin.write(command.encode())
                    server.process.stdin.flush()

    await bot.process_application_commands(message)
```

Comment: Have you got some code that shows how you're starting/adding the asyncio task? What's your `on_message` code look like?

Comment: @ESloman I have updated post with code.

Comment: I don't see any reference in your code to a function named `on_message`, except in the function def statement.  I'm not familiar with this library, but don't you have to pass the name of the function into the library somewhere, so it knows what function to call when a message arrives?